# NameError: name 'pyotp' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, one-time-password

I am using pyotp library for generating the OTP in my Flask Application. It works perfectly in my local. When I upload the flask project in elastic Beanstalk, and try to generate the otp, I get the below error.

```
NameError: name 'pyotp' is not defined
```

The Error stacktrace is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
     raise value
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
   File "/opt/python/current/app/app.py", line 33, in login
     totp = pyotp.TOTP('secretkey')
 NameError: name 'pyotp' is not defined
```

I generated the requirements.txt file which has the pyotp value:

```
  pyotp==2.3.0
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This solution is helpful to me, I use python3 to login remote visual machine.

```sh
pip install pyotp==2.3.0
```